# How to retain the data in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my App, I have first viewController where user gives some input to search the address and finds the related address  in next viewController. What I want is, when user goes back to the first viewController, The data which he entered should retain in the various field.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a navigation based application, then the data would be retained by default. Please make sure that you are not setting it to nil in any of your methods like viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear or other..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have your setup code of the view controller in the viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear. If that is the case try changing it to the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the object is still alive when you go back to the first controller, the data the user entered should still be in the various fields.

Answer (score 0):

How did you present the next viewController?  And how did you go back to the first viewController from the next viewController?  If you go back to the first viewController by creating a new instant of first viewController (from the next viewController) then the previous data would not be there.